# Why can't clipboard content from Mail be pasted if closing Mail?

Tags: windows, email, clipboard

Fairly simple problem but pretty annoying, say I receive some key by email to paste in a software to unlock it.

If I copy the key from the email then close *Mail* immediately, and try to paste, it doesn't work.

Basically, I have to keep *Mail* open for the paste operation to succeed.

Even more puzzling, if I open the clipboard with Windows+V, I can see that the key is in the clipboard, but Ctrl+V never works.

Is there any way to fix this annoying behavior?

Comment: This seems to be pretty common behavior by modern systems and apps. Office programs on Windows will prompt when you close them if you've copied a lot of data from them. I do not know why this is the case, but I'd guess it is to support pasting metadata like style information and the like based on where you're pasting to. And I don't know how to change this behavior except to use an intermediary utility that runs continually in the background to handle the hand off.

Comment: Try googling for a clipboard replacement.  There are many out there and they have more functionality than the default Windows Clipboard.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys!

Comment: sometimes the `CTRL + C`  &  `CTRL + V` doesn't work, and you have to right click and copy/paste the file. See if that works. It works for me and it is very handy for me.   
Although theres no fix for the `CTRL` method, check out https://techpp.com/2022/02/10/best-clipboard-managers-for-windows/ for some (third party) clipboard managers.